# EntityManager is closed : do i have to check all before?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In a lot of framework, when you execute request in your database, tou can catch database errors to throw "user friendly" errors.

When i use doctrine, and for example i am inserting a duplicate value, i have the message "The EntityManager is closed" and it is impossible to continue

Do we always have to check for duplicates, foreign keys before trying to create the entity in doctrine ?

For example, i was doing this in a service :

```
...
foreach ($reponse as $item) {
    $item = new Item();
    $item->setRelationId(item->id);
    $item->setValue($item->value);
    ...
    try {
        $this->em->persist($item);
        $this->em->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Useless because if there is an exception, after this the kernel handler ends the transaction
    }
}
```

What is the good way to do it simply with doctrine ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tou can check if is closed and if yes you can reopen it like this for example:

```
   if (!$this->em->isOpen()) {
        $this->em = $this->em->create(
            $this->em->getConnection(),
            $this->em->getConfiguration()
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when the connection is closed, i have to reopen each connection of the class who are calling my Service ? This code is in a method, but i have to paster youss solution in the class who calls this method to. Am i right ?

Comment: you can check into your foreach if entitymanager is closed, this happens when you make many operations, so you don't need this check every time, but inside this foreach I think is mandatory